# How can i secure app script from the user who is going to use the google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a script to display data in google sheet. But  want to secure my url or in short I want to lock the script. So that now one can edit my script accept me

Comment: There are two basic choices: 1) Library 2) Add-on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The easiest way to do it is to create a [Standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)

Even if the script is used on a publicly shared spreadsheet, nobody apart from you will have access to the script if you do not share the script with anyone.